# Как найти самую продолжительную последовательность, которая может быть либо убывающей либо нарастающей

Tags: python, алгоритм

Есть список

```
[1, 2, 3, 10, 8, 12, 13, 14]
```

Надо найти самую продолжительную последовательность. Например, для примера выше это

```
[1, 2, 3, 10]
```

А для такого списка `[12, 11, 10, 8, 7, 1, 2, 3]` решением будет

```
[12, 11, 10, 8, 7, 1]
```

На `leetcode` я нашёл решение только в одну сторону - либо нарастающая, либо убывающая последовательность. Решение типа - найти сперва для нарастающей, потом для убывающей последовательности, а потом сравнивать где больше элементов считаю `неоптимальным`. Подскажите плиз алгоритм решения

Comment: почему решение где сначала считается возрастание, а потом убывание `неоптимальное`?, для `O-нотации` это все равно остается  сложность `O(n)`, можно конено одновременно выполнять за один проход, но сложность по памяти возрастет. Почему на `[12, 11, 10, 8, 7, 1, 2, 3]` ответ `[12, 11, 10, 8, 7]`, а не `[12, 11, 10, 8, 7, 1]`

Comment: По второму - да всё верно. единичку забыл

Comment: Почему вы считаете не оптимальным решить две задачи и выбрать лучший ответ? Какое решение будет оптимальным с вашей точки зрения?

Comment: Искать надо самую длинную последовательность или самый длинный подмассив? Это разные задачи.

Answer (score 1):

```py
# lst = [12, 11, 10, 8, 7, 1, 2, 3]
lst = [1, 2, 3, 10, 8, 12, 13, 14]

last = lst[0]

lst_lt = [last]
lst_gt = [last]

mx_lt = []
mx_gt = []

for i in range(1, len(lst)):
  
  if lst[i] > last:
    lst_gt.append(lst[i])
    mx_gt = max(mx_gt, lst_gt, key=len)
  else:
    lst_gt = [lst[i]]

  if lst[i] < last:
    lst_lt.append(lst[i])
    mx_lt = max(mx_lt, lst_lt, key=len)
  else:
    lst_lt = [lst[i]]
  
  last = lst[i]


result = mx_lt if len(mx_lt) > len(mx_gt) else mx_gt
print(result)
```